# is it possible to have a static field in C++?

Tags: c++, static

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)
>   [Unresolved external symbol C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13660017/unresolved-external-symbol-c)

I know that you can have static locals and static globals, but is it possible to have static fields? I ask because when I declare a static field (a static variable declared inside a class) I get "unresolved externals" compiler error messages.

Comment: Yes. Just been answered earlier today. See [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13660017/unresolved-external-symbol-c/13660035#13660035

Comment: we unable to answer if you don't put your code or what you did ? ? Here is some reference it might helps you. 1. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/195207/unresolved-external-symbol-on-static-class-members 2. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7510165/c-static-variable-and-unresolved-externals-error

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible. What you have to do is *define* the static member. Typically this is done in the corresponding `.cpp` file:

```
//=== C.h

class C {
  static int i; // declaration
}

//=== C.cpp

#include <C.h>

int C::i = 0;   // definition
```

Comment: Unless it's a constant integral type...